# usage for advanced floating content lite wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I just want to know how to move float content box using advanced floating content lite.

I want to move content box to left middle of my website. I still don't have website, just running on local host.

Please someone tell me what should I add into custom CSS code of that plugin
form top left to middle left.

Answer (score 0):

```
.afc_popup {
    top: 50% !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    right: initial;
}
```

Or search for the unique id (like this: `afc_sidebar_140`)
and place instead of `.afc_popup`